# Is it possible to combine 2 SELECT statements to be used in an INSERT INTO statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have the following SQL script (simplified):

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int);

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT id, 1, amount
FROM transactions
WHERE customerId = 10;

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT TOP(1) id, 5, amount - charges
FROM transactions
WHERE customerId = 10
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

In the above example, I first insert a number of records into the table varilable. then I insert an extra record using the last record.

Is it possible to combine the 2 statements into 1?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **UNION ALL** to combine the 2 select statements:

```
INSERT INTO @table
SELECT id, 1, amount
FROM transactions
WHERE customerId = 10;
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP(1) id, 5, amount - charges
FROM transactions
WHERE customerId = 10
ORDER BY id DESC;
```